# Fault dynamic product menu with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dynamic, menu

I'm making a menu of products that where inserted in the site. Only a fault has come up, and i can't figure out how to fix it.

My code:

```
public function getProductList($type = NULL, $brand = NULL){
  if(empty($type) and empty($brand)){

     $types = $this->productmodel->getTypeList(); // Category as arraylist
     $brands = $this->productmodel->getBrandList(); // Brandnames as arraylist
     $products = $this->productmodel->getProduct(); // All available products

     $menu = array();

     foreach($products as $product) {
          [$product['brand_id']]
          $menu[$product['type_id']] = array (
        'type' => array(
        'url' => base_url('index.php/productcontroller/getProductList/'.$product['type_id']),
        'type_name' => $types[$product['type_id']]
        )
    );

        // Brands
       $menu[$product['type_id']]['brands'] = array (
       $product['brand_id']['brand'] => array(
        'url' => base_url('index.php/productcontroller/getProductList/'.$product['type_id'].'/'.$product['brand_id']),
        'brand_name' => $brands[$product['brand_id']]
        )
    );
}
return $menu;
}
```

Futher explained:

I have three tables in my database. 
1.Type - with: type.id and type_name,
2.Brand - with: brand.id and brand_type,
3.Products - with: all info about products with the id's from the tables from above.

What happens is that only the latest inserted product will be showed. So all the others brandnames are overwritten. I wanted to only overwrite the brand names that are duplicate so therefor i use the (brand['id'])How could i make this work? I use Codeigniter.

Thanks for your time and effort,

Greetings

Comment: note:

Only the last brand_name will be displayed. The type is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$menu[$type_id]['brands']` array on each iteration.  I think you meant -

```
foreach($products as $product) {

    $menu[$product['type_id']]['type'] = array (
        'url' => base_url('index.php/productcontroller/getProductList/'.$product['type_id']),
        'type_name' => $types[$product['type_id']]
    );

    // Brands
    $menu[$product['type_id']]['brands'][$product['brand_id']]['brand'] = array(
        'url' => base_url('index.php/productcontroller/getProductList/'.$product['type_id'].'/'.$product['brand_id']),
        'brand_name' => $brands[$product['brand_id']]
    );

}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you very much. Could you explain me what i did wrong?

Comment: As I said in my answer you were overwriting the array in each iteration - `$menu[$product['type_id']]['brands'] = array (`

Comment: I didn't notice that, is there a trick to help me identify those mistakes in the future?

Comment: Common sense really. If you are expecting an array to contain multiple items but it only has one there is a good chance it is because you are overwriting it. `print_r($menu)` will show you the resulting array structure.